# Choose a k-subset such that its elements 's gcd is maximal

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, divisibility, searching

Given $n$ positive integer and a positive integer k. How to find a subset of size k such that its elements 's gcd is maximal (just give the maximum value of gcd is okay).

---

Example: Give $3$ integers $1, 2, 4$ and $k = 2$; output: $2$ ($\gcd(2, 4) = 2$)

Could this problem be solved efficiently ? I am currently using randomized pruning search algorithm to find such value.

Edit: Since brute-force solution can have some overlap calculations, I am thinking about dynamic programming solution but I got stuck

Comment: This may help, but I'm not sure: if you write the prime factorization of each number, the GCD of $k$ numbers will be the product of the primes [with multiplicity] they have in common.

Answer (score 1):

there is no efficient solution. it reduces to the set cover problem, which is NP complete

so basically, you ask the question, "is it possible to come up with K numbers from this set such that their GCD is at least X" and then find the largest X for which this statement evaluates to true

essentially you are asking whether it is possible to choose some K sets (the factorizations of your list of numbers), such that the union of those sets contains every element in some other target set (the factorization of X)